# how to use hive tables data in another mapreduce program?how to setup eclipse for hive jdbc?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, jdbc, hive

How do I acess hive tables (Query on it) in a map reduce program in eclipse?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04, hadoop-1.2.1 ([Single node](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)), Hive-1.1.0 ([installed 1.1.0](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/how-to-install-apache-hive/))
hive is perfectly working on shell but i want to access tables in  another mapper function to replace key according to data in hive tables
how to configure hive  for eclipse

this is what exactly i want to do:
i have created a table using hive shell

> ip_range_country( start_ip BigInt, end_ip BigInt, country_name String)

here i am using IP_add (12.25.0.4 as 012025000004)

then i loaded data in it through csv file.

now i want to use this table in mapreduce program which takes

> input to map function : 
>   (byte_offset) LongWritable,(ip_add product_name )(Text)
>
> output of map:
>   (Country_name product) Text,(1) IntWritable
>
> **so in map function i want to resolve ip_add to its country name.**

i am doing this complete process in eclipse IDE, how to implement this map function and setup eclipse IDE for it?

Comment: Hive maps data stored in HDFS to defined schema which it stores in metastore, that means Hive stores data in HDFS, so you should be able to write mapreduce program on HDFS data to achieve what you are after.

Comment: How do i call a mapreduce program from other mapreduce to do the same thing as described in question.

Comment: It appears to me that you need a lookup table ? you can use replicated join which can be implemented in Map Reduce to achieve this.

Comment: @Prahalad can you give me some resources or hyperlinks, because I have no clue how to call a mapreduce (which takes  **ip_address** and **.csv file containing start_ip ,end_ip,country_name** and  gives country_name for ip_address )from another mapreduce(which takes a  **log file** as input and calculates how much a product got sold in a country )

Comment: Check MapReduce Design Patterns.